# fancybox with asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

I am developing a asp.net page which send a email. page is loaded in fancybox. problem is when i click the button fancybox close and i am redirected to full page in the browser which i don't want to happen. what i want is keep the fancybox as it is after server side code execute also.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Register with your javascript code in startup script that shows this fancybox. Or put you markup in **UpdatePanel**.
Even better extract email sending code in web method and just call it from you button handler via javascript. It will be real ajax page.

Comment: It works fine. now fancybox doesn't close but now the problem is when i click the button after filling data in fancybox nothing happens to that page but the parent page execute and gives me error megssage

Comment: Hi Did some modification now it doesn't give me a error but aftr executing the fancy box it automatically close and parent it becomes the full page and parent page disappears. i wanna keep the fanxybox page until i close it manually.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the fancy box content? Is it content on the page that is hidden, or is it an separate page.  If it's content on the page, be careful with FancyBox, as it injects the contents as an append to the "body" tag, which will place it outside of the "form" tag. As such, your controls will do nothing.  You can hack the code by looking for

`.appendTo( 'body')`

and change it to:

```
.appendTo( 'form')
```

If it's loading from another page (which has it's own Form element), make sure you are loading it as an iFrame (unless your other page is making AJAX calls)

```
$('a.fancyLink').fancybox({type:'iframe'});
```